# Browser page doesn't auto-refreshes in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function SecretComponent() {
  return <p>Secret2 information for authorised users only </p>;
}

function RegularComponent() {
  return <p>Everyone1 can see this component</p>;
}

function App(props) {
  if (props.authorized) {
    return <SecretComponent />;
  } else {
    return <RegularComponent />;
  }
}

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App authorized={false} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

In my react project in Visual Studio Code when I make a change the browser page refreshes only if a change is made in the App.js file but doesn't refresh when a change is made in the index.js file. I have to refresh the page manually to show the change.

Comment: Can you share a repo example ?

Comment: are you using `create-react-app` ?

Comment: `npx create-react-app <app-name>` and I run it with `npm start`

Comment: When I change value in `authorized={true}` I noticed this change doesnt not propage in Bowser dev Components. Authorised  still shows  `authorised: false` until I refresh browser. After page is refreshed the value sync with code base.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. npm install `react-hot-loader`
2. In `app.js` , add `import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'` .
3. Wrap the `App` component while exporting `export default hot(App)` like this.

Comment: I tried it. It doesnt make any difference.

Comment: This issue has been opened up in github , see if it could help you . [Auto reload does not detect changes to index.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9984)